# How can I listen to multple actions in NGXS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I'm in the process of converting an application from NgRX to NgXs. In NgRx, I could 'listen' to multiple actions in an effect and react appropriately to them. How can I accomplish this using NgXS?

In NgRx, I may have something like the following in an effect

```js
this.actions$.pipe(
 ofType(fromCustomers.pageLoaded),
 ofType(fromCustomers.pageRefreshed)
)
```

I see in NgXs that the `@Action` decorator can accept and array of action types, but I'm confused on how get the value from the multiple action types when delcaring the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NGXS, you can listen to multiple actions via `@Action` decorator, like the following:

```js
@Action([fromCustomers.pageLoaded, fromCustomers.pageRefreshed])
pageLoadedOrRefreshed(
  ctx: StateContext<YOUR_STATE_MODEL>,
  payload: fromCustomers.pageLoaded | fromCustomers.pageRefreshed
) {
  // do some stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Amer! That works perfectly. I'm assuming that I'll need to ensure that the action type payload is the same, but that shouldn't be hard to remember.

As an aside, but related, do you know best practice on utilizing states in different modules? For example, if I have a customer module with it's state and then a cart with it's state. If I have an action that's going to effect the cart state, is it best practice to listen to that action in the cart? Or should the customer state reference the cart state and listen and react to it in it's own state? Not sure if that makes sense.